# How to place ArrayList into an AbstractTableModel?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList<String[]> data` which I place values into at a different point in the program, I have made it a variable of MyTable which extends AbstractTableModel. But I don't know how to place it into the table.

I have previously put a `String[][]` into the table, but I am not sure how that would work with ArrayList class.

For `getRowCount()` I can do `newStringArr.length` and for `getColumnCount` I can do `newStringArr[0].length` and for `getValueAt(int row, int column)` I can return `newStringArr[row][column]` for a `String[][]` type. What would be the equal of those functions for an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Is this for Swing, JavaFX, SWT, Vaadin? Add a tag for whatever UI kit you are using.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) is a good example using `AbstractTableModel`.
In your case, `MyTable` can be defined as:

```
class MyTable extends AbstractTableModel {
    private final int numRows;
    private final int numColumns;

    private List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public MyTable(int numColumns, int numRows) {
        this.numColumns = numColumns;
        this.numRows = numRows;

        init();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return data.get(0).length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Optional<String> getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        if(isNotValidEntry(row, col)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Out of bound row or col");
        }

        return Optional.ofNullable(data.get(row - 1)[col -1]);
    }

    public void setValueAt(String value, int row, int col) {
        if(isNotValidEntry(row, col)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Out of bound row or col");
        }

        data.get(row - 1)[col - 1] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    private void init() {
        IntStream.range(0, numRows)
                .forEach(r -> data.add(new String[numColumns]));
    }

    private boolean isNotValidEntry(int row, int col) {
        return numRows <= row - 1 || numColumns <= col - 1;
    }

}
```